# How to change site language by URL like apple.com/ru/

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'd like to make change inURL for example:

```
localhost:8080/shop/phones/?language=ru to localhost:8080/shop/ru/phones/
```

I tried a lot but anytime I got no result.

My .htaccess:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on

ErrorDocument 404 /shop/PageNotFound.php 
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

RewriteBase /

#Default Language
####RewriteRule ^(us|de|fr|ru)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
####RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?language=us [L,QSA]
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your complete htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /shop/PageNotFound.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop/phones/\?language=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /shop/%1/phones? [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/phones/?$ /shop/phones/?language=$1 [NC,L]

#Remove php exten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still trying this, the URL works, but it returns 404

Comment: What url are you going to?